# I can't identify this kanji from pokemon moon

Tags: writing-identification

[image: I cannot identify the first kanji of the second sentence. I have tried SKIP and hand drawing it but it was to no avail. I have also tried the kanji finder via radicals over at JDIC but again it was for naught.]

I cannot identify the first kanji of the second sentence. I have tried SKIP and hand drawing it but it was to no avail. I have also tried the kanji finder via radicals over at JDIC but again it was for naught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at 粗相（そそう） which would mean "careless mistake".

Comment: Thanks!! Sometimes the kanjis end up looking a bit off in 3ds games.

Comment: @QuistisTrepe: Ah, the joys of pixelated writing...  Good luck!